# show series converges by root test

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

Let $x$ be a real number with $|x|< 1$, and $q$ be a real number. Show that the series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty n^qx^n$ is absolutely convergent, and that $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} n^qx^n= 0$

My Solution:
Apply the root test
$$\alpha:=\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}|a_n|^{\frac{1}{n}}= \limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}|n^qx^n|^{\frac{1}{n}}\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}n^{\frac{q}{n}}|x|$$
but, $$|x|<1$$
$$-1<x<1$$
$$-n^{\frac{q}{n}}<x n^{\frac{q}{n}}<n^{\frac{q}{n}}$$
$$\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}-n^{\frac{q}{n}}<\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}x n^{\frac{q}{n}}<\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}n^{\frac{q}{n}}$$

given $$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} n^{\frac{1}{n}}=1$$, we have:
$$\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}x n^{\frac{q}{n}}<1$$
Hence, the series converges.

Is my solution correct?

Answer (score 2):

You dont even need to do all the stuff with the inequalities at the beginning,

$$\limsup |n^{q} x^n|^{1/n} = |x| \limsup|n^{q/n}| = |x| < 1$$